# Should I use the address element in the header?

Tags: html

I can't find any definitive answer on this... please take a look at this fairly generic HTML page for example; Header with logo on the left, Company name and address on the right. I would like to know if it's appropriate to use the `address` element in this way?

```
<body>
<header>
    <img src="/logo.jpg" alt="Bobby's Bits">
    <address>
        <h1>Bobby's Bits</h1>
        14 Milkyway cresent,<br>
        The Moon
    </address>
</header>
<main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae dignissimos doloremque iusto tempore quae quisquam dicta nobis. Vitae officiis sequi pariatur amet odit possimus, necessitatibus dolore consectetur quas at, alias.</p>
</main>
<footer>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</footer>
</body>
```

**Edit**

The most semantic way to do this - I think - is to also combine the vCard as follows:

```
<body>
<header>
    <img src="/logo.jpg" alt="Bobby's Bits">
    <address class="vcard">
        <h1 class="fn org">Bobby's Bits</h1>
        <span class="adr">
            <span class="street-address">14 Milkyway cresent,</span>
            <span class="locality">Mare Serenitatis</span>,  
            <span class="postal-code">M00 N11</span>
        </span>
    </address>    
</header>
<main>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae dignissimos doloremque iusto tempore quae quisquam dicta nobis. Vitae officiis sequi pariatur amet odit possimus, necessitatibus dolore consectetur quas at, alias.</p>
</main>
<footer>Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</footer>
</body>
```

Not entirely sure if putting the `h1` inside the vCard is 'allowed' but I can't see why not. If anyone wants to wade in with further advice please feel free. I wish there were more clearly defined guidelines on this.

Comment: Hard to see why not....

Comment: Yes, my thinking also, although it doesn't seem to be commonly used like this even though this kind of generic page layout *is* common..?

Comment: Yes you can do it like that. I would have done the same thing.

Comment: @Kamelkent would you also use the vCard format? (Please see edit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [W3 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-address-element) does not set any restrictions on which tags it can appear in, and in fact their example and typical usage is that it would appear in the `<footer>`. The `<header>` tag is in the same semantic category as `<footer>` so there is no reason why you cannot put it there.

There is however a restriction that it should not technically contain any "heading content", i.e. `<h1>...<h6>`, only describe the contact information. So you should not put the site name in `<h1>` tags inside the address element. You can still style that line in larger text tho.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks. So if I want to keep the h1 for SEO purposes, I now have to shoehorn that into my markup somewhere else. Awesome ಠ_ಠ